# Help select prior function

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, gamma-distribution

I have a certain population of individuals, each of which produces a certain 1D output described by a random variable $X$. To a reasonable approximation, for an individual, $X$ is normal-distributed with some unknown mean and standard deviation (STD). The goal is to estimate those mean and STD on an individual level. The problem is that individuals sometimes produce only a dozen or so datapoints, and there is a risk of severely underestimating the STD because the sample is too small to be representative. I would prefer to slightly overestimate the STD, rather than underestimate it. My idea is to introduce somewhat conservative priors for the population mean and STD, and find a posterior for mean and STD which is a compromise between the prior and the likelihood. Since performance is a concern, I would prefer an analytical solution for the posterior. Since I do not need iterative updating, I do not have to have a conjugate prior, but merely a prior that would allow me to find an analytical expression for the posterior. Further, I do not need a perfect solution. The ultimate goal is to get the marginal posterior distribution for the individual mean, and thus make a qualitative estimate of its uncertainty via, e.g. [HPDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credible_interval).

In order to find a reasonable guess for the prior, I have computed the distribution of the sample means and STDs over the individuals, for which a large number of samples was available. It looks like this:

[image]

Originally I was hoping to fit it with [normal-gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal-gamma_distribution), but, as far as I understand, this model does not account for correlation between mean and STD which is clearly present.

Could you recommend a 2D prior function for (mu, std) that would be an ok fit for the above distribution, and that would result in an analytic posterior given gaussian likelihood? I am not 100% married to the gaussian likelihood either. I would at least consider another unimodal likelihood if it allows me to get to an analytical posterior.

**EDIT 1**: The data is guaranteed to be positive.

**EDIT 2**: I have now tried the advice of taking the logarithm and it works like a charm - the mean and the variance are no longer correlated. Log-transformed data seem to more or less fit to the normal-gamma 2D distribution, although the mean has slightly long tail. Perhaps gamma-gamma 2D would be better, but since it is not that easy to invert I'll live with normal-gamma, since it is not too bad really.

Comment: What would things look like, if you worked on the log-scale (assuming these values can never be 0 or negative)? The distribution looks a bit skewed like it could be log-normal (or something else, of course) and log-transforming might even reduce/get rid of the mu to SD relationship.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, transforming the data to try to get rid of correlation sounds like the simplest approach. I'll try logarithm and maybe a few other transformations.

Comment: If I understand well you have a population $i=1,2,...,n$, with $X_{i}\sim Norm(\mu,\sigma^{2})$. However, at some point you say "The problem is that individuals sometimes produce only a dozen or so datapoints", does this mean that $X_{i}$ is a vector or realization from $Norm(\mu,\sigma^{2})$?

Comment: @Fiodor1234 I'm sorry, I am not too familiar with terminology (i.e. I don't know what 'vector representation' is, sorry). There are $m$ individuals, and each individual produces a different number $n_i$ of datapoints $X_{i,j} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \sigma_i)$. I want to infer the individual parameters $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i$. I know that they themselves are sampled from the prior distribution plotted above. I actually don't care about $\sigma_i$ and only want the marginal posterior $P[\mu_i| Data]$

Comment: Also, are the individuals indepedent?

Comment: @Fiodor1234 yes, the individuals are most certainly independent

Comment: So, I guess can I assume that all the $\mu_{i}$ are independent?

Comment: Yes, that is the case

Comment: And one last thing, what is the relative size of the $n_{i}$??

Comment: @Fiodor1234 $m$ is on the order of 1000,  $n_i$ are quite different. For good participants it can be like 40-50, for bad participants it can be like 5. (P.S. Merry Christmas)

Comment: This seems like the situation that multi-level models (also called  mixed effects models, hierarchical models) are designed for. Have you considering using a multi-level model?

Comment: Unfortunately, you're pretty limited if you want an analytic prior.  If the lognormal recommendation of @Bjorn above doesn't work, you might want to consider non-analytic approaches, e.g., MCMC, which will really open up the possibilities.

Comment: it might be a bit naive but...   I'd go with a 3D normal prior $\theta\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_0,\Sigma_0)$. $\theta_1$ as the mean, that's easy. $\theta_2$ is not too much by itself but we can take $\theta_2^2/\Sigma_{22}$ which has a $\chi^2$ distribution, next $\Sigma_{22}/\theta_2^2$ has inverse gamma distribution which fits the variance. Last but not least, as you mentioned the varying number of observations per individual, $\theta_3$ can model $n_i$ using the Poisson-to-normal relation. And it'll have a nice analytical form.

Comment: @Eli I'm sorry, I am not familiar with multilevel models. Do you think they could help? My main concern is that one way or another I will have to calculate a probability distribution of a nested quantity, whether it is called posterior or something else. This operation either is doable analytically or it is not. Currently for me numerical methods are not an option.

Comment: @Spätzle I understand each individual sentence in your comment, but together they do not yet form a picture in my head. How do I use this to find the marginal posterior for the mean of each observation? Will that posterior be analytical? Perhaps you can write an answer?

Comment: @AleksejsFomins, I asked about multilevel models because this is the canonical example of when to use them. I thought there might be some reason why they wouldn't work that I wasn't seeing.  I'll write something up or at least provide a link.

Comment: Generally speaking, you need a two-stage prior here. as mentioned above, you need a hierarchical Bayesian model. you can see this video for some general idea: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wz5BJBZ-zCQ. regarding my previous idea, you should have three priors, each befitting its variable: a normal, a gamma and another normal

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common use-case for hierarchical models. These models have a lot of different names, so you'll sometimes see them called multi-level models or mixed-effects models. Hierarchical models aren't strictly Bayesian, but, in my experience, they are more common fit as Bayesian models than Frequentist.

The basic idea is that you define population parameters then have member of the population distributed around the population parameters with their own variability.

In your example, let $i$ denote the person and $j$ denote the measurement. $X_{ij}$ refers to measurement $j$ on person $i$. Each person does not need to have the same number of measurements, $j$. Each person has their own mean, $\theta_i$, and variance $\sigma^2_i$. The person-level means are distributed around an overall mean, $\mu$.

- **Individual Level**: $X_{i, 1}, X_{i ,2}, \dots, X_{i, j} \sim N(\theta_i, \sigma^2_i)$ for $i = 1, \dots, n$
- **Population Level**: $\theta_1, \dots \theta_n \sim N(\mu, \tau) 
  \\ \mu \sim N(0, 10), \; \tau \sim U[0, 10] \; \text{(or some other noninformative priors)}$.

You'll be to get a posterior distribution of each person-level mean, as well as the population level mean and variance (or precision).

Hierarchical models are too big a topic to explain in a Stack Exchange post. You can [look](https://www.y1zhou.com/series/bayesian-stat/bayesian-stat-hierarchical-models/) [into](http://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.com/2012/11/shrinkage-in-multi-level-hierarchical.html) [some](https://widdowquinn.github.io/Teaching-Stan-Hierarchical-Modelling/07-partial_pooling_intro.html) [resources](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ebrian/463-663/week10/Chapter%2009.pdf) to help you fit these models.